# Customizing navigationBar in iOS7 - title color not working

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to customize the navigationBar of a navigation controller in iOS7 and the title color is not changing. I am doing the following:

```
    [navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:46.0f/256.0f green:46.0f/256.0f blue:46.0f/256.0f alpha:1]];
    [navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
    [navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{[UIColor whiteColor]:UITextAttributeTextColor}];
    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The navigationBar translucency gets turned off and it is dark, but the title also stays dark. I've also tried to create a custom label and set it as the title view with not much luck.

How can the title color be changed?

Comment: Got it - [navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];

Comment: For the record, the dictionary you're passing to setTitleTextAttributes has the key/value the wrong way around. It should be: `[navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor whiteColor]}];`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
```

Answer (score 66):

The appearance api continues to evolve, and UITextAttributeTextColor is now replaced with NSForegroundColorAttributeName.

```
[navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

I'll add two things:
The key comes first, then the object.

If you want to globally change your nav controller's title attributes, use the appearance api:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

I'd put that appearance api call in your app delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

UPDATE: Might as well post the Swift equivalents.

To update the navigationBar for an individual view controller, one can use:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

To change the navigation bar's appearance throughout an entire app, one can use:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Comment: Yes, UINavigationBar - not UINavigationController.  Thanks for the fix, lari.

Answer (score 12):

Not working for me.
Using UINavigation as a modal view controller.

Apparently title colour needs to be set uiapplication level

Edit:

Best way is to change the navigation title in each VC context:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil]];
```

Answer (score 4):

In swift you'll do the following:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor(),
    NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)
]
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift + UIAppearance version:

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .blackColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = .Black
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem in the OP's code is this line:

```
[navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{[UIColor whiteColor]:UITextAttributeTextColor}];
```

The text color attribute name and value are mixed up. It should be

```
[navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

Answer (score 0):

actually looks like a bug. Try

```
myViewcontroller.title = @"";
navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
myViewcontroller.title = @"TITLE";
```

works.

Answer (score -1):

## In Swift 4

*NSForegroundColorAttributeName* was renamed to *NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor*

#### So If You're looking to change the navigationItem title's color:

```
let navBarAppearance = self.navigationController!.navigationBar    
navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
```

I used **UIColor.white**, just insert any **UIColor** you want the title to be.